# Is this Eloquent Model design is good for performance?

Tags: php, laravel

I have about 4 models

1. user_invoices
2. payment_vendor [companyVendor]
3. payment_vendor_methods [bank, ewallet,...]
4. payment_vendor_channels [name A,name B,...]

Currently those point (2,3,4) are linked or connected to user_invoices

Case: I want to use point (4) only then retrieve other from that Model

Migration (UserInvoice)

```
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('payment_vendor_id')->nullable();
    $table->foreign('payment_vendor_id')->references('id')->on('payment_vendors')->cascadeOnDelete()->cascadeOnUpdate();
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('payment_vendor_method_id')->nullable();
    $table->foreign('payment_vendor_method_id')->references('id')->on('payment_vendor_methods')->cascadeOnDelete()->cascadeOnUpdate();
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('payment_vendor_channel_id')->nullable();
    $table->foreign('payment_vendor_channel_id')->references('id')->on('payment_vendor_channels')->cascadeOnDelete()->cascadeOnUpdate();
```

I want to change it into this

```
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('payment_vendor_channel_id')->nullable()->after('payment_vendor_method_id');
        $table->foreign('payment_vendor_channel_id')->references('id')->on('payment_vendor_channels')->cascadeOnDelete()->cascadeOnUpdate();
```

So, there is only need to get the channel then we can retrieve other relations [payment_vendor and payment_vendor_methods].

I still doubt about the performance which one to choose. I am thinking that the second design is more efficient but dunno the performance.

Should I do second approach? or back to the old one

To retrieve payment_vendor

```
$payment_vendor_channels->payment_vendor->name
```

To retrieve payment methods

```
$payment_vendor_channels->payment_vendor_methods->name
```

Is this design is good for performance? Or should I go back to my old design. This is my first month with Laravel, I am sorry to ask a silly question like this.

Here I define the model for you to have a better understanding

Model UserInvoice

```
use HasFactory;

protected $guarded = ['id'];

<!-- HIDE -->

public function payment_vendor() : BelongsTo{
    return $this->belongsTo(PaymentVendor::class);
}

public function payment_vendor_method() : BelongsTo{
    return $this->belongsTo(PaymentVendorMethod::class);
}

public function payment_vendor_channel() : BelongsTo{
    return $this->belongsTo(PaymentVendorChannel::class);
}
```

}

Model PaymentVendor

```
    use HasFactory;

    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    public function user_invoice() : HasMany{
        return $this->hasMany(UserInvoice::class);
    }

    public function payment_vendor_method() : HasMany{
        return $this->hasMany(PaymentVendorMethod::class);
    }

    public function payment_vendor_channel() : HasMany{
        return $this->hasMany(PaymentVendorChannel::class);
    }
```

Model PaymentVendorMethod

```
    use HasFactory;

    protected $guarded = ['id'];
    public function payment_vendor() : BelongsTo{
        return $this->belongsTo(PaymentVendor::class);
    }

    public function payment_vendor_channel() : HasMany{
        return $this->hasMany(PaymentVendorChannel::class,'payment_method_id');
    }

    public function user_invoice() : HasMany{
        return $this->hasMany(UserInvoice::class);
    }
```

Model PaymentVendorChannel

```
    use HasFactory;

    protected $guarded = ['id'];
    public function payment_vendor() : BelongsTo{
        return $this->belongsTo(PaymentVendor::class);
    }

    public function payment_vendor_method() : BelongsTo{
        return $this->belongsTo(PaymentVendorMethod::class,'payment_method_id');
    }

    public function user_invoice() : HasMany{
        return $this->hasMany(UserInvoice::class);
    }
```

Comment: It might not be a "silly" question, but it may be deemed an Off-topic: Opinion-based question.  `Is this design is good for performance?` ...well, "goodness" is relative.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion, anyway what do you think if I have to remove "payment_vendor_method() and payment_vendor_channel()" from UserInvoice Model. Then, I depend on payment_vendor_channel() to get the relations?

Comment: You should run some tests/profiling to check if it's good _enough_ for you in your case, which isn't something we can answer (not knowing anything about your application/the size of the data/the server/requirements etc.)

Comment: @M.Eriksson so both design is appropriate to use? I run profiling they did the same performance. I  am still seeding the data to make it biggest.

Comment: I think what they mean, is that nobody can say if a design is 'appropriate'. You have to consider lots of things and this cannot be answered in one question(thats not a stack overflow question). Consider testing both your solutions and see if you can work with them.